# DistinctBy 3 Params

Tags: c#, morelinq

I am trying to use C# MoreLinq to try to figure out duplicates.

Here is an example. There is a league, within the league the teams.  Each player in the team can play any position.

```
public sealed class Triad
{ 
    public int Id1 {get;set;}
    public int Id2 {get;set;}
    public int Id3 {get;set;}
}
```

With this I want to GroupBy

```
ArrayOfTraids.GroupBy(new { Id1, Id2, Id3}).Select(t => t);
```

Example

If Id1 = 1, Id2 = 2 and Id3 = 3, in this example we would get 1 Object.

The problem I want to solve is, If Id1 = 2, Id2 = 3, Id3 = 1, I want it ALSO to be apart of the same list, since the int values are still 1,2,3 (regardless of the order, they are still the same values).

I feel this could be very simple but I am unsure.

**SOLVED**

Ended up doing something like this

```
ArrayOfTriads.Where(t => t.Id1 < t.Id2 && t.Id2 < t.Id3)
```

Which eliminated the repeating.  Closed.

Comment: Answering your question directly `players.DistinctBy(p => new { p.Prop1, p.Prop2, p.Proper3 })`

Comment: @abatishchev That only works if the Player stays as Position 1 all the time.  If Player A moves to Position 2, its consider a new "Team".  I don't want it to.  I have  a feeling its simple, but not that simple. :)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Give me an example of inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Xela updated with more in depth example.

Comment: Please post the data (**sample input, desired output**) in more formal way, not just plain English, e.g. the Player class definition, etc.

Comment: @abatishchev Updated again.  Hopefully more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer:

```
ArrayOfTriads.Where(t => t.Id1 < t.Id2 && t.Id2 < t.Id3)
```

Does not work with the following example. It filters out the first two elements instead of selecting one of them:

```
ArrayOfTraids.Add(new Triad(3, 2, 1));
ArrayOfTraids.Add(new Triad(2, 3, 1));
ArrayOfTraids.Add(new Triad(1, 2, 4));
ArrayOfTraids.Add(new Triad(1, 2, 5));
```

You get:

```
Id1 Id2 Id3
1   2   4
1   2   5
```

I think that you may want to group by the ordered Id's.  Here is a way it could be done:

```
ArrayOfTraids
.GroupBy(m => (string.Join(";", new List<int> { m.Id1, m.Id2, m.Id3 }
.OrderBy(n => n)))).Select(m => m.First());
```

This produces:

```
Id1 Id2 Id3
3   2   1
1   2   4
1   2   5
```